# checking if a map contains a value in Freemarker Template

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to check if a map contains a value to conditionally execute some freemarker code. This is what I've got so far:

```
<#if productLayout.layoutWidgetConfiguration[pos.id]??>
    <#assign configId>${productLayout.layoutWidgetConfiguration[pos.id]}</#assign>
<#else>
    <#assign configId></#assign>
</#if>
```

But I get this error, which basically fails the if condition.

```
Error executing FreeMarker template freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException: For "...[...]" left-hand operand: Expected a sequence or string (or something that's implicitly convertible to string), but this evaluated to an extended_hash (wrapper: f.t.SimpleHash):
==> productLayout.layoutWidgetConfiguration  [in template "admin/pages/catalog/products/partials/productLayoutEditorRefreshZone.ftl" at line 7, column 22]

The failing instruction (print stack trace for 9 more):
==> #if productLayout.layoutWidgetConfigu...  [in template "admin/pages/catalog/products/partials/productLayoutEditorRefreshZone.ftl" at line 7, column 17]
    at freemarker.core.DynamicKeyName.dealWithNumericalKey(DynamicKeyName.java:141) ~[DynamicKeyName.class:2.3.20]
```

How can I check if a value exists in a map in a freemarker template?

---

Update Here:

It seems the hash doesn't like a Long key value if I change it to this, the if check works, but the value doesn't get retrieved even when it exists - so I guess the question now is how to retrieve a value from a hash with a `java.lang.Long` key?

```
<#assign configId = "">
<#if productLayout.layoutWidgetConfiguration[pos.id?string]?has_content>
    Hello
    <#assign configId = productLayout.layoutWidgetConfiguration[pos.id?string]>
</#if>
<h1>${pos.id}</h1>
```

Comment: So I got this working, but took the "simpler" approach of converting my (luckily) transient hash to use string keys (refer here: http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_nonstring_keys) - now my code is a total mess of type conversions, but it works again at least... (I totally regret moving from JSTL to Freemarker)

Comment: Why don't you just use `?api`, which is also described in the FAQ you have linked?

Comment: Seemed a bit long winded to get the configuration going - it's not that big a deal for this instance to make the key a String.

Comment: Well, flipping the `api_builtin_enabled` configuration setting to `true` is hopefully less long winded that making "a total mess of type conversions" out of your code. (Even if it implies an FM update, not doing that will also just result in losing more hair...)

Comment: OK, usually there are two settings to tweak, not one, as if you are using the default object wrapper, the `incompatibleImprovements` setting of that also has to be increased to 2.3.22, or of the `Configuration` itself. Backward compatibility complications...

Comment: No worries, I'll keep it in mind if there's any more issues like this one that pop up - the type conversion problems are mostly related to Hibernate because I have to convert Sets to transient hashes to bind to Spring forms, if I use Lists, the performance degrades, this just adds a little more complexity to that problem because now I'm converting keys as well...but not a big deal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` only supports string hash (`Map`, etc.) keys and numerical sequence (`List`, array, etc.) indexes. For now the solution is not using `[]` for `Map`-s with non-String keys. You can use the Java API of the object instead, like `myMap?api.get(nonStringKey)`, etc. Note that `?api` has to be allowed in the configuration; see http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_buitin_api_and_has_api for more.